# scons -u and variantdirs

Tags: python, c++, build, scons

I've been working with SCons for a while now and I'm facing a problem that I can't manage to resolve, I hope someone can help me. I created a dummy project that compiles a basic helloWorld (in main.cpp). What I want to do is compile my binary from 'test' folder using the scons -u command. All of my build is done in a variant dir that will eventually be created at the root of the project (build folder).

Here's my folder tree :

```
+sconsTest
       -SConstruct
       + test
                  -SConscript
                  +test2
                             -SConscript
                             -main.cpp
       +build (will eventually be created by scons)
```

Following is the SConstruct code:

```
env = Environment()
env.SConscript('test/SConscript', {'env' : env})
```

Following is test/SConscript code:

```
Import('env')

env = env.Clone()

env.SConscript('test2/SConscript', {'env' : env}, variant_dir="#/build", duplicate=0)
```

Following is test2/SConscript code:

```
Import('env')

env = env.Clone()

prog = env.Program('main', 'main.cpp')
```

After placing myself in 'sconsTest/test' folder, I type in scons -u, I expect it to build my program, however all it says is 'test' is up to date. When nothing is compiled. I noticed something, when I remove both variant_dir and duplicate args from test/SConscript, the scons -u works.

Furthermore, I noticed it was possible for me to compile the program using the command

```
scons -u test2
```

However, I'm using scons on a large scale project and I don't like giving a relative path as an argument to compile my project. I want scons -u to automatically build everything it finds in subdirs.

Do anyone have any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Your `test/SConscript` mentions `test1`, but your question only describes `test2`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, my apologize, it's a typo. I fixed it in the post. Still stuck with same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [MAN page](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html) again. The `-u` option will only build default targets at or below the current directory. This excludes your folder `sconsTest/build` when you're in `sconsTest/test`.

What you are looking for is the `-U` option (with the capital "U") instead. It builds all default targets that are defined in the SConscript(s) in the current directory, regardless of what directory the resultant targets end up in.